# PHP/MYSQL Help - unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, mysql, database, syntax

I am trying to make a edit profile page and i want the user to be able to change there username and email address. I've been going at this problem now for sometime and need your help.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

```
$edit = mysql_query("UPDATE users (Username, EmailAddress) VALUES('".$newusername."', '".$newemail."') WHERE UserID="$_SESSION['UserID']"");
```

Comment: I suggest you read about [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) and [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're missing some dots around `$_SESSION['UserID']`

```
$edit = mysql_query("UPDATE users (Username, EmailAddress) VALUES('".$newusername."', '".$newemail."') WHERE UserID=" . $_SESSION['UserID']);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['"

Comment: @ritch: Please read Marek's answer carefully. You didn't use his code. I suggest you read about [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) and [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: @ritch: You must move the dot after `$_SESSION` after `['UserID']` so you have `UserID = ".$_SESSION['UserID'].""`. And as Marek wrote, you may omit concating the empty string, so you have: `UserID = ".$_SESSION['UserID']`.