# "unexpected T_VARIABLE" when creating string?

Tags: php, string, syntax-error

I have been staring at this for 20 minutes now and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
// Create query
$qry = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id='"$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']"'";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/dkitterm/public_html/test2/member-profile.php on line 24

Comment: I've edited your question, that is now the answer.

Comment: @Webarto I've rolled it back; that's not how editing works.

Comment: Then handle copy/pasta answers.

Comment: If only you were using placeholders ... you would have 1) avoided this error entirely, 2) have cleaner looking code, 3) stopped potential injection attacks. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401319/php-mysql-help-unexpected-t-variable

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709824/mail-form-in-php-syntax-error-unexpected-t-variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.useful-funcs) the string literals with the variable with the `.` operator:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id='" . $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] . "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate your string:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id='" . $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] . "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

The less cumbersome approach is using string interpolation. You're already in a double quoted string, so why not utilize its one distinct feature?

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id='{$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']}'";
```

That's terser and less room for syntax errors.
See also http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double
(There's a shorter syntax even, if you read on.)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
 //Create query
 $qry="SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id='" . $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] . "'";
 $result=mysql_query($qry);
```

You forgot the concatenation operator, `.`

Answer (score 0):

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id='" . $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] . "'";
```

You must concentrate your strings with . operator